# How to bind Variables of View to ViewModel in WPF MVVM?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a created a window ( WPF and MVVM ) - say PrintWidow ( so I have PrintWindow.xaml , PrintWindow.xaml.cs , PrintWindowViewModel.cs- viewmodel)

Now I am going to use(call) this `PrintWindow` obj from some other class on  button click or on some command trigger , I want to set Document Source  for this PrintWindow(following  MVVM).

How would I do this ? I created a `PrintDocument` object in PrintWindow.xaml.cs and tried to bind it as follows : (obviously just a blank try - as I cannot do this declaration in XAML)

```
private PrintDocument printDocuementView;

public PrintDocument PrintDocuement
{
    get { return printDocuementView; }
    set { printDocuementView = value; }
}

//constructor
public PrintWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new PrintViewModel();

    Binding b = new Binding();
    b.Source = printDocuementView;
    b.Path = new PropertyPath("PrintDocumentCommand"); // "PrintDocumentCommand" is defined in View Model class and is responsible to set the `PrintDocument` object there.

}
```

This code (obviously) doesn't work. How should I go about it.
Summary : I want to open `PrintWindow` from another window and eventually set some Property of `PrintWindow` from code behind of the 'other widow' object.The query is - where should this property go? View ? ViewModel? ?? *puzzzeled*

I have googled for answers - but couldn't relate any to my problem.

I am a Freshman for `WPF` and a Rookie for `MVVM`.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to open the PrintWindow from another window? Or do you want to add a button to the PrintWindow to activate some functionality?

Comment: Have a look at this [MVVM Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126249/MVVM-Pattern-in-WPF-A-Simple-Tutorial-for-Absolute)

Comment: @bitestar: I want to open Print WIndow from another window . 
and eventually set the source document from code behind or the 'other widow'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `PrintDocumentCommand` is in your `PrintViewModel` but you're setting the Source of this Binding to an instance of the `PrintDocument`-Class, it can't be found, because the Binding is looking for the `PrintDocumentCommand` in `PrintDocument`-Class.

If you want to open the PrintWindow from another Window, place the `PrintDocument`-Property and the `PrintDocumentCommand` in the ViewModel of the other Window. Now your function that is executed through the `PrintDocumentCommand` could look like:

```
private void Print()
{
    PrintWindow pw = new PrintWindow(PrintDocument);
    pw.ShowDialog();
}
```

The constructor of your PrintView could be like:

```
public PrintWindow(PrintDocument pd)
{
    InitializeComponents();
    this.DataContext = new PrintViewModel(pd);
}
```

and now you can access the PrintDocument in your PrintViewModel.

Comment: I fail to understand - what would i bind my `PrintDocumentCommand` to , if I remove the `b.source`. The Rest I am doing already .

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you want to do, have a look at my edit ;)

Comment: Thanks, worked for me (although with with few alteration specific to my project) - But Workd. :)